# How can I check if one of the two variables is none? like if (mask1 | mask2) is None:

Tags: python

the expression `if (mask1 | mask2) is None:` returns this error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

How can I check if one of the two variables is `None`?

Comment: should this be true if any of them is `None`, or only if one is `None` but the other is not `None`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value) It is not an exact duplicate as they are testing for values and OP for `None`, but still the accepted answer applies here also

Answer (score 7):

```
if mask1 is None or mask2 is None
```

Should work

Answer (score 2):

Not as Pythonic but this would also work

```
a = 1
b = 2

None in (a, b)
>> False

b = None

None in (a, b)
>> True
```

Comment: IMO, this might be **more** pythonic. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Nice, but `in` also uses `==`, not `is`, so might fail in the (rather esoteric) case of an object pretending to  be `__eq__` to `None`

Comment: correct @tobias_k hence why I mention it might not be as Pythonic although that depends on OP's use case, as is being debated in another answer

Comment: This *will* work. The problem is it is anti-pattern to use equality checks, where identity checks are more appropriate. The place where this will bite you is if you try it with `True` / `False`... ie `True in (a, b)` will return `True`. Equivalently `False in (0, 1)` will return `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Update: OP's exception message indicates he is checking `integer` vs `None`. Equality checks will NOT suffice. Consider `mask1 = 0`, `mask2 = None` both will fail falsey equality checks.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'int' and 'NoneType'

If you are testing for identity for an arbitrary number of elements:

```
any(map(lambda x: x is None, (mask1, mask2, ..., maskN))  # OR operation.

all(map(lambda x: x is None, (mask1, mask2, ..., maskN))  # AND operation.
```

As user @Jean-François Fabre mentioned get rid of the `map` / `lambda` operation:

```
any(x is None for x in (mask1, mask2, ..., maskN)) # OR
```

These will all short-circuit because in Python 3 list comprehension will return an iterator that `any` can evaluate at each step. Same with `map` / `lambda` those operations return iterators as well. So which you prefer is a stylistic choice.

If you only have two conditionals, then the other answers (that use identity checks, not falsey checks) will suffice.

Comment: You don't need `any` **and** `map`, just `any` will do as in the other answers

Comment: @DeepSpace The other answer, which was deleted because it was incorrect? :p

Comment: Depends on the OP's use case. If he is checking identity then this approach is correct. If he only needs falsey values then those approaches will work. It is up to the developer to decide what the intent is.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Perhaps a different answer using `any` but *is* correct :P using `any`, `map` **and** a `lambda` seems like a huge overkill for such a simple task. Why not `any(val is None for val in list_of_masks_or_explicit_tuple)` ? We don't know exactly when OP wants this to be `True` but it's irrelevant since it can be easily changed

Comment: "Neither of the above will short-circuit though. So you could always optimize using an early exit": not true. It will stop as soon as condition is known

Comment: but better written as `any(x is None for x in …)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Depends. In Python 2, the `map` is evaluated entirely before checking the `any` (which will short-circuit). But unless noted otherwise we should certainly assume Python 3.

Comment: I think the way I wrote it with the lambda means all values will be evaluated first. In your version, `x is None for x` should return an iterator, which should allow short circuiting. Good suggestion.

Comment: @DeepSpace The generator comprehension code you posted is 100% identical to the `map` code in Python 3, except syntactically. Which to prefer is purely a matter of preference. It’s definitely not conceptually simpler.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Python Zen suggests otherwise...

Comment: `map` prevents short-circuiting in Python 2, because it returns a list of Boolean values. In Python 3, `map` creates an iterator that only applies the function as `any` or `all` requests a value. After `any`/`all` stop asking, `map` stops mapping.

Comment: It's too early and too cold for me. Yes, lambda / map is identical because they also return iterators. Therefore, both are equivalent as pointed out by Konrad.

Comment: @KonradRudolph *Simple is better than complex*. If they are the same, use the simpler one...

Comment: "in Python 3 list comprehension will return an iterator that any can evaluate at each step" That's not entirely correct, either. With a list comprehension, `any([...])` would again not short-circuit (or rather, `any` would, but before that the entire list would be created), but `any(...)` without `[...]` does not use a list comp. but a generator expression.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The difference is more than `syntactically`. Timewise they are not the same. `map` + `lambda` add overhead on large sequences. I tested for a sequence of 1,999,999 non-`None` values + one `None` in the end (worst-case, no short-circuiting). My approach was 2 times faster than the suggested `map` + `lambda`. For more complex use-cases this overhead will be even more significant

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check for AND (i.e. all the checks are `None`):

```
if all(x is None for x in (mask1, mask2)):
   # execute codes
```

If you need to check for OR (i.e. any of the checks are `None`):

```
if any(x is None for x in (mask1, mask2)):
   # execute codes
```

You might also consider using `set` to check:

```
if {mask1, mask2} == {None}:
   # execute codes for when all are None

if {mask1, mask2} > {None}:
   # execute codes for when any is None

if {mask1, mask2} - {None}:
   # execute codes for when any is not None.
```